# Unable to connect to SQL database, get network Error26

Tags: sql-server, connection-string

I have a local database 'Model' and I need to connect to it through my 2 applications. One application is based on only a subset of tables defined in my database 'Model'. My connection string is

```
<add name="Model"
     connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Model;Integrated Security=True;Trusted_Connection=true;"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I use the same connection string for both applications. Application 1 (less tables) connects and loads data just fine. The problem is Application 2 is throwing me error:

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
```

All the solutions on net are based on checking if I have the right connection string and if I have the remote session enabled, all this works because my Application 1 works. 
What can be going wrong with Application 2? Where should I start looking for an issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the Data Source to  `(local)` or if you are running SQL Express try `(local)\SQLEXPRESS`

failing that can't you take a look at the connection string that "Application 1" is using?

Comment: I tried with \SQLExpress and it still throws the same error. Application 1 uses exactly the same connection string and works fine. What else can I try?

Comment: Yes, I am using Entity Framework. I have another connectionstring for another database which connects fine I think.